# Convert WCHAR to QString in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, wchar

Convert WCHAR to QString in Qt.
Please help me to implement it to complete this convertion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are to/from `WCharArray` methods that are static members of `QString`:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromWCharArray

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toWCharArray

Comment: It looks like these links are broken

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks for the heads-up.  Fixed 'em.  But I sure wish these guys would have read Tim's [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).  :-/

Comment: You might want to consider editing to include an example as well.

Comment: `QString::fromUtf16()` also works. I was getting linking errors in QT 5 on using `QString::fromWCharArray()`. see https://forum.qt.io/post/165335. Linking error I was getting - `unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QString __cdecl QString::fromWCharArray(unsigned short const *,int)" (__imp_?fromWCharArray@QString@@SA?AV1@PBGH@Z)`